# Trying to pass value from one protected method to other

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass value from one protected method to other.
I am storing file name and file path in one protected method Upload1()

```
 protected void Upload1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Extract Image File Name.
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

            //Set the Image File Path.
            string filePath = "~/Uploads/" + lblTdcNo.InnerText+"1"+lblRevision.InnerText;

            //Save the Image File in Folder.
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));

        gvImages.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
       }
```

and trying to pass filename in submit method of a button click,basically want to store image name which has been uploaded.

```
 protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string img1 = FileUpload1.FileName;

     }
```

but not getting idea how to do that in case of image uploading any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: use a global class level static variable will serve your purpose. Otherwise methods/events don't talk to each other.

Comment: have you tried using session?

Comment: Session["filename"]="your path";

if(Session["filename"]!=null){string filename = Session["filename"]; Session["filename"]=null; }